# MySQL Change SUM value

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to create a query whereby I `SUM` a column but, if a column contains a certain value, the `SUM` value has to be reset at that point to take on this value.

ie:

```
SUM(i.units * op.add_or_subtract)   // This would translate to: '50 * -1' or '50 * 1'
```

The idea is that if `op.op_code = 9`, the `SUM` value should be reset to the current value of `i.units` as a manual adjustment has taken place.

```
op_code | units | add_or_subtract | SUM value |
--------|-------|-----------------|------------
   1    |   50  |       1         |     50
   1    |   50  |       1         |    100
   4    |   30  |      -1         |     70
   9    |  225  |       0         |    225
```

etc etc.

Can anyone help with how I could (if I can) achieve this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select *, case when op_code = 9
               then @s := units
               else (@s := @s + (units * add_or_subtract)) 
          end as sum
from your_table, (select @s := 0) st
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks to work the way I want. Much appreciated. Is the purpose of the (select @s := 0) to initialise the variable?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(op_code = 9, (@var_sum := units), 
                           ((@var_sum := @var_sum + units) * add_or_subtract) 
          ) as sum_value
FROM table_name, (SELECT @var_sum := 0) a;
```